# tokenizing a string using C++

Tags: c++, regex, tokenize

I have a string

```
"server ('m1.labs.teradata.com') username ('user5') password ('user)5') dbname ('default') "
```

I want to separate it as

```
string1 = server
string2 = 'm1.labs.teradata.com'
```

and password has a ')' in it.
Can anyone help me out in how to use it using regex.??

Comment: Could you please show your current code?

Comment: I dont have one. Need to write one

Comment: Yes, you do. After you post a [mcve], we can help, but we're not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I only tested the regex to extract your items, but I think the following code snippet will work.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "server ('m1.labs.teradata.com') username ('user5') password ('user)5') dbname ('default') ";
    std::regex rgx("server\s+\(\'[^']+\'\)\s+username\s+(\'[^']+\'\)\s+password\s+\(\'[^']*\'\)\s+dbname\s+\(\'[^']+\'\)");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), match, rgx)) {
        std::cout << "match: " << match[1] << '\n';
        std::cout << "match: " << match[2] << '\n';
        ....
    }
}
```

In the following example you will iterate over all matches in the regular expression.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string str("server ('m1.labs.teradata.com') username ('user5') password ('user)5') dbname ('default') ");
    std::regex r("server\s+\(\'[^']+\'\)\s+username\s+(\'[^']+\'\)\s+password\s+\(\'[^']*\'\)\s+dbname\s+\(\'[^']+\'\)");
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_search(str, m, r);
    for(auto v: m) std::cout << v << std::endl; // Here you will iterate over all matches
}
```

For your other querstion with passing string to a function:

```
void print(const std::string& input)
{
    cout << input << endl;
}
or a const char*:

void print(const char* input)
{
    cout << input << endl;
}
```

Both ways allow you to call it like this:

```
print("Hello World!\n"); // A temporary is made
std::string someString = //...
print(someString); // No temporary is made
```

The second version does require c_str() to be called for std::strings:

```
print("Hello World!\n"); // No temporary is made
std::string someString = //...
print(someString.c_str()); // No temporary is made
```

Comment: On which cpp version are you running it. I am getting \s,\ as unknown escape character..?

Comment: I need to extract the strings "server" "username" etc.. How shall I do that? And the output for ur code is :
match: 'm1.lab(s.teradata.com'
match:
Why am I not getting the others? I had used the following code :
int main()
{ const std::string s = "server ('m1.labs.terad(ata.com') username ('user5') password ('user)5') dbname ('default')";
    std::regex rgx("\(\'[^']+\'\)");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), match, rgx)) {
        std::cout << "match: " << match[1] << '\n';
        std::cout << "match: " << match[2] << '\n';
    }
}

Comment: then you need to double escape it like \\s+

Comment: suppose this code is der :
int main()
{
    const std::string s = "server ('m1.labs.terad')ata.com')username ('user5')password('user)5')dbname ('default')";
    std::regex rgx("\(\'[!-~]+\'\)");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), match, rgx)) {
        std::cout << "match: " << match[1] << '\n';
        std::cout << "match: " << match[2] << '\n';
    }
}
The output is:
match: 'm1.labs.teradata.com'
match: 

I am not getting the other matches . Why is that?

Comment: with match[1], match[2], match[3] and match[4] you will get the other matches

Comment: I am not able to get it by that way.

Comment: Did you understand the regular expression i wrote? Then please try the other example which i edited in my post

Comment: That worked fine for me
Now I want to extract only the : server, username, password: 
For that I am using the re:     regex re("[a-z]+\(\'");
But i am not able to print them. Please help me out with this. if I am missing out on anything

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark my answer done. I will help you with you regex to extract only the server

Comment: I had one more doub, that if I want the extracted tokens in form of string. I need to pass in another function. How will I do that?

Comment: Till now I am able to extract server , username as well as their attributes properly using the tokeniterator variable 'i'. I want to pass this as a string to another function.
How will I do that.
Apologies for so many doubts.